# Can the employees use the documentary in legal situations?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-office

Can the employees from *The Office* use the documentary in legal situations?

I don't mean being allowed to film a situation like [The Deposition](https://theoffice.fandom.com/wiki/The_Deposition).

In the episode [Broke](https://theoffice.fandom.com/wiki/Broke), Michael negotiates the buy-out of TMPC to Dunder Mifflin. They verbally agree to all the terms, but during the meeting nobody writes anything down, no notes are kept.

What's to stop Dunder Mifflin from changing the agreement?

David argued against the terms, because it would cost DM millions of dollars.

Even if Michael, Ryan, and Pam claimed the agreement was changed, why would anybody believe them? No evidence exists, Ryan isn't trusted by corporate, which leaves Micheal and Pam, whom DM could claim are two disgruntled employees attempting to take advantage of DM.

Presumably off screen, contracts were written, and Michael, Ryan, and Pam signed them, and they agreed terms were met. So we can safely assume that DM didn't try to back out.

Is there any canon or official source that can confirm if the footage of the agreement was used to support Michael, Ryan, and Pam, or if the footage can be used in legal situations?

Comment: I believe this is addressed in one episode (or more). I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Why would DM back out of the agreement? They'd be exactly back where they started... In the very next episode we see Michael, Ryan and Pam working at DM again (and Charles was no longer Michael's manager), and that was their only terms, so obviously DM held up to 100% of the agreement that was made in the conference room.

Comment: @Charles - Because as David stated, it would cost millions of dollars to buy TMSPC. Backing out and waiting was their best option, as Dwight tried to point out, TMSPC was broke and so all they had to do was not agree to anything and wait for the clients to be free and come back. Jim intervened and made Dwight look stupid, so Charles never listened to his advice. They agreed to a lot more terms, health insurance for 3 people (dental for Michael), and bringing Pam into sales.

Comment: @SvetlanaofVodianova You're actually missing a crucial detail from the conversation that may make the premise of the question moot.  By the time they agreed to hire everyone on, David Wallace _knew_ that TMSPC was worthless.  Michael spills the beans near the end of negotiations before they agree.  Michael's ultimate trump card was that he had plenty of names for new paper companies to make when TMSPC goes under; and was willing to keep making new paper companies just to keep taking DM clients.

Comment: @AH! I see. Make it an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @JMac What?? No, that's **not** the motivation behind Wallace accepting Michael's offer. First off, the "millions of dollars" was to be taken loosely because either way the branch needs a manager, needs so many salespeople, a receptionist, etc. Michael and company being hired back **is not** the same as a flat buy out. In fact, DM came out on top because they didn't have to pay anything extra to get their lost clients back, they simply moved around management and employees. Sorry but the OP has no weight it because DM ***did*** hold up to their agreement 100%.

Comment: After that meeting, just as Wallace stated, he went back to the board of directors and voiced the events that occurred (and obviously they accepted). From there, DM's legal team drafted all the necessary documents, the MSPC was acquired by DM and everything went back to normal, more or less (Pam did come back as a salesperson and Ryan got "his old job back"). The meeting that we saw in the conference room was the very first of several meetings. How could DM have had all the necessary documents to sign if the terms of agreement hadn't even been hashed out yet?

Comment: The ultimate factor for DM accepting the offer though was like Michael said -- "all [Michael] has to do is wait out [David Wallace], given the upcoming investor's meeting". That being said, I'm sure David Wallace portrayed the MSPC as much more powerful/dangerous than what he believed them to be.

Comment: @Charles What do you mean "That's not the motivation"?  Clearly the motivation was that Michael had no plans of relenting, even though in David Wallace's eyes it was more costly to hire them than do a flat buyout.  He was willing to do the flat buyout; but had to be convinced to hire them instead.  Most of what you're saying seems completely irrelevant to the conversation.  OP is talking about a hypothetical, he acknowledged that DM did go ahead with the contract as is.  All this other stuff is pure speculation and seems quite irrelevant.

Comment: Honestly I was trying to hold off on this but really, VTC since any answer that's accurately provided will be legally based and has nothing to do with the show itself.

Comment: OP is asking about the legality of using documentary footage as evidence in a verbal agreement. Has nothing to do with The Office itself.

Comment: @JMac - Please tell me which parts of my question are irrelevant so I can remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'll turn this into an answer, though I think Flater gave a pretty good answer to the actual question as posed.

I don't want to dig too much into the first question.  I'm not sure if they could use the documentary in a legal situation; but I would definitely be reluctant to go back on a verbal contract when it was recorded on video; regardless who the rights belong to.  It would take some very specific documentary contract wording to be sure that the video couldn't come back to bite you.

> What's to stop Dunder Mifflin from changing the agreement?
>
> David argued against the terms, because it would cost DM millions of dollars.

Dunder Mifflin wouldn't want to change the contract.  It was *DM's* idea to buy out The Michael Scott Paper Company.

When David Wallace protested the million dollar buyout, he mentioned something along the lines of TMSPC not being worth that much.  Michael then spilled the beans that his company was worth *nothing*.  Michael then made it clear that even when TMSPC goes bankrupt, he will just create another paper company to take DM clients, and another after that; because he has "no shortage of names".

This is when David Wallace agrees to the buyout, only after discovering that TMSPC is worthless.  Either side trying to change the agreement wouldn't be beneficial at this point.  DM wants TMSPC off their back, and TMSPC employees just want stable jobs.  By the time the deal is made, David Wallace has about as much information as the viewer, and still decides to go through with it.  There's no real reason in the show for him to back out.

Answer (score 1):

> *What's to stop Dunder Mifflin from changing the agreement?*

What's to stop Dunder Mifflin from changing the agreement **even if either party takes notes**? The note taking doesn't make a difference.

The only thing that matters is the contract that TMPC and DM sign - which doesn't happen on screen but there is no reason to believe that the contract was any different from the agreement.

Cinematographically, there's nothing interesting about showing *both* the meeting and a reading of the contract, if both contain the same information.

> Is there any canon or official source that can confirm if the footage of the agreement was used to support Michael, Ryan, and Pam, or if the footage can be used in legal situations?

There is no confirmation on the agreement between DM and the documentary makers, so this cannot be answered in-universe.

If you want a real-world answer, this is better asked over at Law.SE, assuming that there is existing legislature that can override the specifics of the agreement between DM and the documentary makers.

Comment: *The note taking doesn't make a difference.* Actually it does make a difference, there is a record about what both sides agreed on. Remember in the deposition, they had someone taking notes? Both are legal situations, and if the documentary can't be used in a legal situation then DM can change the agreement.

Comment: @SvetlanaofVodianova: Neither party can be considered as an authenticated source of what was actually agreed. What happens if one party makes different notes than the other party? Depositions are on a completely different legal scale than business meetings and nowhere near comparable. In depositions, there is an impartial and sworn in stenographer whose career relies on the accuracy of their notes.

Comment: *Depositions are on a completely different legal scale than business meetings and nowhere near comparable.* Agreed! But they could get an impartial 3rd party to record the notes, just like the deposition.

Comment: @SvetlanaofVodianova: "This could've also happened" doesn't contribute to the question about what actually happened.